# what is kernel.Bind and Ninjnect web?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kernel

I am new in ASP.NET and I have some questions .

What is Kernel.Bind? Why are we using it? What is ninjectweb and why do we use kernel there?

Answer (score 0):

**Kernel :**   The kernel  is a computer program in operating system. The kernel is control over everything in the system. Kernel is first programme loaded when computer start.
    In short, The Kernel connects the application software to the hardware of computer. The kernal is control the memory management, device management, system call.

**Kernel.Bind in DI :**  In dependencies injection kernel is used to manage our application. In this the bootstrapper class is also used.

The main concern and reason behind that the kernel.bind is used to bind our application proccess  and request with our system(computer) kernel.  In short, kernel.bind is used to bind our application request to the main computer system kernel.

Kernel.bind is used to communicate with system kernel.  In that reason our application is lossely coupled and work fast and we controll our application excecution.

**NinjectWeb :**  Ninjectweb is a dll that can be used for DI. In which Ninject.web.common, ninject.web,mvc, ninject.

After installing NinjectWebCommon class is created in which we create kernel object and bind with kernel that are explain above.

Hope that will be helpful for you.